# Load a dict-like string which includes None value using python

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

Assume there is a string like `'{"a": None}'`. How to let Python know the existence of `None`?

This is the error I have been receiving:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 7 (char 6)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: If you are trying to decode a JSON, which is implied by your error, you should use `null` instead of `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "letting python know of the existence of None," but you can easily convert the string to a dictionary by using the eval function like so:

```
json_entry = eval('{"a": None}')
print(json_entry["a"])
```

Output:

```
 None
```